# how to send POST using retrofit, await process and receive response JSON?

Tags: java, android, api, post, retrofit

In my app, I send a json with information to the server, which is processed and after having a result, it returns another Json response. I don't know how to read that response Json.

this is part of code:
`

```
private void sendData(String tipo, String dni, String instrucciones, String video) {
    progressDialog.setMessage("wait ...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    ApiInterface apiInterface = SendDeviceDetails.getRetrofit().create(ApiInterface.class);
    final PostModel postModel= new PostModel(tipo, dni, instrucciones, video);
    Call<PostModel> call = apiInterface.PostData(postModel);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<PostModel>() {

         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<PostModel> call, Response<PostModel> response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, response.body().getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
            }
            

         }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<PostModel> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "error in conexion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });
```

`

It runs fine on submit, process, I can read the result of the service, but I don't know how to read the response json
The server sends me this json:
results JSON :{"status":"1","message":"ok","ID":"609691","NAME":"xxxxxxxxx"}

Comment: Inside the response.isSuccessful() if block you can call the response.getBody() method which returns PostModel class object according to response json

Comment: I am a beginner, I would ask you please tell me the code that I should use for it. Thank you

Comment: To clarify. The Json sent is different from the Json received.

Answer (score 0):

you declare  model class look like this

```
        public class PostModel {

// request
..................
........

// response
@SerializedName("status")
public String status;

@SerializedName("message")
public String message;

@SerializedName("ID")
public String ID;

@SerializedName("NAME")
public String NAME;
}
```

read response

```
   PostModel postModel = response.body();

   String message = postModel.message;

   Toast.makeText(context, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to send the PostModel model as a request object and receive the PostResultModel object as a response. Then you create the interface with the method:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    Call<PostResultModel> postData(@Body PostModel request);
}

public class PostResultModel {
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("NAME")
    private String name;

    // getters and setters 
}
```

You can use this method like this:

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = SendDeviceDetails.getRetrofit().create(ApiInterface.class);
final PostModel postModel= new PostModel(tipo, dni, instrucciones, video);
Call<PostResultModel> call = apiInterface.postData(postModel);

call.enqueue(
   new Callback<PostResultModel>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<PostResultModel> call, Response<PostResultModel> response) {
         if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            final PostResultModel postResultModel = response.body();

            // todo some logic with reponse
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<PostResultModel> call, Throwable t) {
         // todo some logic when request failed
      }
   }
);
```

See [this article](https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23) to get more information